# Iterator throwing an error when converting to string*

Tags: c++, string, iterator

Consider the following piece of code, where: `list<string> elements`

```
bool SearchElement(const string& product) {
   for (list<string>::iterator it = elements.begin(); it != elements.end();i++) {
      string& element = *it;

      if ( element == product) {
        return true;
      }

   }

   return false;
}
```

I want to rewrite it using a pointer:

```
bool SearchElement(const string& product) {
    for (list<string>::iterator it = elements.begin(); it != elements.end();i++) {
        string* pelement = it;
        if ( *pelement == product) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

But it is throwing an error:

> C:\Users...\C++\IShoppingApp.h:141: error: cannot convert
> 'std::__cxx11::liststd::__cxx11::basic_string<char >::iterator' {aka
> 'std::_List_iteratorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char >'} to
> 'std::__cxx11::string*' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string*'} in
> initialization In file included from C:/Users/....

My professor said an iterator is roughly speaking a pointer, so I expected to use it as such. Why  am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you referring to `string& pelement = it;` in the second function where you say you want the iterator to be treated as a pointer? There's no pointer there. Did you mean to try `string* pelement = it;` instead?

Comment: @cigien yes, sorry a typo. I fixed that

Comment: elements is a list<string> by the way

Comment: Why do you need a pointer at all?

Comment: If you want a pointer to what `it` refers to, you probably need `&*it`. You want to convert something that is roughly a pointer to an actual pointer.

Comment: Your indentation is extremely confusing and has very little consistency or structure. I'd strongly recommend adopting a common style because going ahead like this will only lead to more frustration and irritation.

Comment: @tadman It is just for learning.The professor said it can be done with a pointer by writing string* pelement = it; when I tried it I got this error

Comment: Most "C++ professors" have almost no idea what they're talking about, so do take everything they say with a huge grain of salt. Case in point here: In C++ the goal is to avoid using pointers whenever possible. Anyone who teaches the opposite is honestly just dealing bad advice.

Comment: A large percentage of C++ professors are Java professors who were blackmailed into teaching C++, hence the many misunderstandings about pointers and when they're appropriate (the fact that pointers use `new`, which is used for *everything* in Java is not helping matters).

Comment: @tadman Can you show how would the code look with a good indentation/structure?

Comment: It's not really important *what* format you use, it only matters that it's readable. Here's a convenient tool you can use http://format.krzaq.cc/ Just paste your code in there and click "Format" and see the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An iterator acts like a pointer, but it is not a pointer. It refers to a value, but it is not itself a pointer. You can get a pointer, though:

```
string* pelement = &*it;
```

Note that although `&` and `*` are inverse operations on regular pointers, they are not so in general, and many types (specifically, iterators) override `*` to behave differently, so the two do not cancel out. It's also possible to override `&`, although there are fewer justifiable use cases that I can think of for that.

Based on the comments, I think you already understand this, but you want a reference. Raw pointers are generally frowned upon in modern C++, and a reference clearly conveys your intent of "I'm borrowing this for a second, I might modify it, but I'm not responsible for deleting it". Getting it to a pointer for educational purposes is fine, but the reference approach is the correct C++ way to do what you're doing.

Comment: I don't think the conversion to a pointer is guaranteed to work for all iterator types.

Comment: @cigien. What type of iterator am I using?  I saw in https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ that the classification is done according to functionality, isn't that just a description? Your claim implies they have different behavior / implementation

Comment: I meant that the iterator is not guaranteed to be the same as a pointer, depending on the iterator to the specific container being used. e.g. this won't work for `std::vector<bool>::iterator`.

Comment: "*It's also possible to override `&`, although there are fewer justifiable use cases that I can think of for that*" - it is usually only smart pointers that do that. But if you needed to account for types that override `&`, you can use [`std::addressof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof), eg: `type* pelement = std::addressof(*it);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau what is the difference between & and addressof?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO like Silvio said, the `&` operator can be overridden, to return something other than the address of the object it is called on (for instance, the address of an internal member).  `std::addressof()` returns the proper address of the passed variable, even if it does override `&`.

Comment: @cigien While I agree with you, `std::vector<bool>` breaks just about every rule of C++, when it comes right down to it, so "`std::vector<bool>` is weird in this case" is almost implied :P